# In the sentence「みどりがきれいなまちです」, why is が used?

Tags: particle-が, relative-clauses

And how should the sentence be translated? 
"It's a beautiful green town"? 
"It's a beautifuly green town"? 
"It's a greenish beautiful town"?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/9831

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36487/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52677/9831

Comment: Reading the post, it looks more like a question about what modifies what. And from the translation examples, OP clearly interprets みどり as an adjective which might be a point of confusion. It's a noun, hence "beautiful greenery".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

みどり in this sentence is not an adjective ("green", "greenish"), but a noun meaning "greenery".

きれい is an adjective modifying the above noun.

The whole sentence reads then as "It is a town with beautiful greenery".

---

が in effect does not connect two adjectives, but a part of relative clause. Either みどりのきれい or みどりがきれい can be used here, see [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/11104).