# Relative clauses: 多い人 vs 多くの人

Tags: grammar, adjectives, relative-clauses, i-adjectives

I was practising a grammar pattern, so in my personal example I wrote:

```
多いオーストラリア人
```

However, a native speaker corrected me with:

```
多くのオーストラリア人
```

I understand that in relative clauses that adjectives go before the noun (e.g. おいしい牛乳). How come they corrected me like this? How does this work? Or did I learn relative clauses wrong?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59713/7810

Answer (score 3):

多い is just a special case word, where, on its own modifying a noun, it takes the form 多くの. However, it can take the 多い form attributively as part of a longer relative clause such as オーストラリア人の多い場所 'a place where there are many Australians'.