# How to parse 「店は人の多いところがいいです」

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

> 店は人の多いところがいいです
>
> <sup>Book translation: stores are better (to be) located at heavily trafficked places.</sup>

My question is related to [Relative Clauses: 多い人 vs 多くの人](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/66648/relative-clauses-%E5%A4%9A%E3%81%84%E4%BA%BA-vs-%E5%A4%9A%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AE%E4%BA%BA) in which the answerer provides a similar example to the above:

> オーストラリア人の多い場所
>
> <sup>Given translation: a place where there are many Australians.</sup>

---

### 人の多いところ

My understanding is that の marks the subject of the adjective 多い, which can be replaced が for emphasis.

1. 人が多い
2. 人の多い + ところ

Overall, it means "A place with lots of people." Assuming this parsing is correct, I move on to my next question.

### Can 店は人の多いところがいいです be ambiguous?

ところ means "place" but it can also be used to refer to a point in time. Therefore, can the above sentence convey the meaning "It's good when the shop is crowded"?

Comment: ところ can refer to a place in time, but that's an unlikely translation with 店 because 店 are located in space (not particularly time).  But with a word like 商売 I think the ambiguity would better come out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been working with and in Japanese off and on since about 1988, but I'm not a native speaker, so take this with a grain of salt.  :)

### How to parse 店は人の多いところがいいです

> 人の多いところ
> My understanding is that の marks the subject of the adjective 多い, which can be replaced が for emphasis...
> Overall, it means "A place with lots of people."

Your parsing so far is correct.

### Can 店は人の多いところがいいです be ambiguous?

I don't think so.

You point out:

> ところ means "place" but it can also be used to refer to a point in time.

The term ところ used to refer to a point in time is, I think, <s>always</s> *usually* in the context of a verb phrase:

- するところ → just about to do
- しているところ → in the moment of doing
- したところ → just finished doing

I don't think it refers to time with *most* adjectives, where instead it refers to an aspect of something (as in 「彼女【かのじょ】のいい[と]{●}[こ]{●}[ろ]{●}」 "the good aspects of [my] girlfriend"), or to a location (as in 「蚊【か】のいない[と]{●}[こ]{●}[ろ]{●}」 "a place without mosquitoes", or 「カバの少【すく】ない[と]{●}[こ]{●}[ろ]{●}」 "a place with few hippos").

### Can the above sentence convey the meaning "It's good when the shop is crowded"?

I don't think so.  To convey the sense of *"the point or span in time when a quality is present"*, I'm much more accustomed to seeing the word とき used instead:

> 店【みせ】は人【ひと】の多【おお】い[と]{●}[き]{●}がいいです

(Albeit, this isn't "crowded" so much as just "there are a lot of people".)

#### Addendum

As pointed out by @[Nameless](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/45630/) in the comment to this post, there are sometimes cases where `[ADJ]+ところ` refers to a moment or time, such as 「忙【いそが】しい[と]{●}[き]{●}」 "a busy moment".

I think the reason that doesn't work here with 店【みせ】 and 人【ひと】の多【おお】いところ is because a 店【みせ】 is inherently a "location", as noted by @[A.Ellett](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/4875/) in the comment on the question, so ところ in context must mean a place.  Meanwhile, because neither a person nor a person's current state is a "location", 忙しいところ cannot refer to a "busy place" and still make sense in that context.

Comment: Thank you for answer. My book provides an example which uses an adjective to refer to a point in time: `お忙しいところどうもすいません`. This, according to my book, translates as `I'm sorry to trouble you when you are busy`.

Comment: Aha, good example @Nameless!  That's one I've heard, which escaped my mind earlier.  I'll tweak my post accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

> 店は人の多いところがいいです

A sentence like this is fine only when there is enough context. Without any context, this is a very vague sentence. My interpretations (in the order they came to my mind) were:

1. I (usually) prefer crowded places within a shop/restaurant.
2. The good point of shops/restaurants (in general) is that I can find many people there.
3. Shops/restaurants should be located at a crowded location.
4. When you go to a shop/restaurant, choose one that has many customers.
   <sub>(I somehow didn't notice this until @Chocolate mentioned it, but this is also a natural interpretation.)</sub>

In 1, 3 and 4, ところ refers to (three different kinds of) physical places. In 2, ところ refers to an abstract aspect (cf. [Meaning of ところ in アメリカのいいところ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23738/5010)).

ところ [can refer to a point of time](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62181/5010), but in this case I could not think of a possible interpretation where ところ means time point. Something like 人の少ないところを狙って店に入る would mean the same thing as 人の少ない時を狙って店に入る.

Comment: 1,2,3 私もです。私はもう一つ、「店（で買い物するor食事する場合etc）は、人の多い店のほうが（品物の回転が速いので新鮮だからor人気がある証拠だから）いいです。」もいけるかな～と思いましたが、どうでしょう？

Comment: @Chocolate あ、確かに。言われてみればそれが一番自然かも。

Comment: 英語圏出身である故かもしれませんが、個人的に3,4が頭の中に先ず浮かんでくる解釈です。日本語圏出身の観点から見ますと、1,2のほうが最初に当たる解釈でしょうか。興味深いです。

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi どれも文脈によっては全く問題ない解釈なので、順番はあまり関係ない気がします。今見ると、なんとなく2と4が他よりは自然かもしれません。普通は店の中の混んでいる場所を好む人はいないので。